# Storing exceptions in a list

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to catch all exceptions and store them in a C# list.  How do I do that.  I created a custom exception class that contains my custom exception. I then created another class called ExceptionsList which contains a list of type exceptions as follows:

```
static List<Exception> exceptionList = new List<Exception>();
```

I store all exceptions captured by adding it to the list.  I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Any examples?  or how to do you stop an exception from being thrown and just store it a list and continue.  Specifically, I'm asking because I would like to continue on error when running a selenium automation tests.

Comment: This seems like a _bad idea_.  What is your reasoning behind needing/wanting this?

Comment: *"I am not sure if I am doing this correctly"* -- if you add them and then they're there, I guess you're doing it correctly. Why do you ask? Do you have any reason for doing this, or is it like my neighbor storing old newspapers in the hallway?

Comment: I've never heard of this before. What is the purpose?

Comment: Why do you want to store the exceptions?

Comment: log them away as they occur (to permanent storage), if you must. a list in memory will be gone if a severe exception occurs that terminates the process and leave the consumer of this data with less diagnostic information even than an unhandled exception would.

Comment: "how to do you stop an exception from being thrown" you don't - at some level you can _handle_ the exception via a `catch` block, but whatever code threw the exception has stopped by that point. What value does keeping the exceptions in a list give you?

Comment: It it to be able to continue a unit test on error and bubble up and provide a list of exceptions

Comment: I refuse to provide an answer to "how to eat an exception and stuff it into a list" on the grounds that I might, one day, wind up maintaining this nightmare.

Answer (score -3):

Exception can be handled in a catch block than logged in a file to see later what went wrong(if you handle exception the automation script will continue working),  rather than storing in a list.

refer to example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#example

```
try
{
    int []  n = new int[10]; 
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("num:" + n[i])
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception in printing values"+ex);
    } 
}
Console.WriteLine("we are here");
```

Since the size of array is 10 (0-9) and we are trying to access the index 10 it will throw the exception `Index out of range` but we catch and print that exception and Program will continue do what it meant to do further.